# Why is my relative positioned element top/bottom not working/jumping to wrong position?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm writing a carousel widget and am having problems with relatively positioning two link-handles.

Both handles should be positioned midway (using CSS `top/bottom`), but when loading the page, only CSS `left/right` are set correctly, while `top/bottom` are not working.

Here is a JSBIN: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/1278/)

Strangely enough, if I switch on/off the CSS rule in Firebug, the handle is positioned correctly. Even better, when clicking on it, the handle jumps back to its "wrong" position

My CSS:

```
ul.ui-carousel {
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  outline: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul.ui-carousel li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  -webkit-border-radius: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  overflow: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
}
ul.ui-carousel li a {
  -webkit-border-radius: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: auto;
  width: inherit;
  }
ul.ui-carousel li a img {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-row-group;
  float: left; /* fix for gap made by Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
}
.ui-carousel.ui-carousel-handles li img {
height: inherit;
}
.ui-carousel.ui-carousel-inset.ui-carousel-handles {
    max-width: 93%;
}
.ui-carousel.ui-carousel-inset.ui-carousel-handles,
.ui-carousel-handle-left,
.ui-carousel-handle-right {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ui-carousel-handle-left.ui-carousel-handle-inset {
    margin-right: .25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-carousel-handle-right.ui-carousel-handle-inset {
    margin-left: .25em;
    display: inline-block;
}
.ui-carousel-handle-left:not(.ui-carousel-handle-inset) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    right: 0%;
    top: 45% !important;
    z-index: 1;
}
.ui-carousel-handle-right:not(.ui-carousel-handle-inset) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -1em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    right: -97%;
    top: -42% !important;
    z-index: 1;
}
.ui-carousel.ui-carousel-inset.ui-carousel-handles {
    margin: 0;
}
```

**Question:**
Why are my handles not positioned correctly, ie why are `left/right` working and `top/bottom` don't? What about the strange jumping? Any idea how to "force" the links to show where they should?

Thanks

**EDIT**:
I know this could easily be fixed with using position absolute/relative. But I want to try and get it to work without using the standard `absolute/relative` way.

Comment: you have to use `position:absolute;` for that and set te parent as `position:relative;`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that. So I would like to know if there is another way

Comment: `position:fixed;` you can not set a pixed element with `position relative`

Comment: let's try. Thanks so far.

Comment: @kougiland: works for one instance, but as soon as I have multiple instances of my list, I'm in trouble

Comment: make sure that your elements are unwrapped. Can you post the code for multiple instances please? or make a dabblet.com if you don't want to publish you code.

Comment: something like this: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/1279/edit)

Comment: ok let me ask you something are you trying to make a pure css carousel or a carousel with jquery ?  because you have a lot of `<a href="#" class="ui-carousel-handle ui-carousel-handle-left ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-carat-l ui-shadow ">Left</a>`

Comment: neither. one with jQuery Mobile :-)

Comment: but i don't see any jQuery in your jsbin  just use one element with the click event

Comment: but the bin shows the problem, so it's a CSS issue.

Comment: please have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/4WxRC/  and no offence please why are you making a carousel with `table` ?

Comment: no offence taken. That was just for the bin :-)

Comment: so what are you using UL, li, divs ... because `table` makes it very hard give me a sec i will try it out but if table is just for the bin denn we should live it and use what you are using in your webapp/software if that's ok ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ul.ui-carousel li a{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%!important;/* this will solve your problem*/
    margin-top: 23px;
}

ul.ui-carousel li a.ui-carousel-handle-left{
    left: 0;
}


ul.ui-carousel li a.ui-carousel-handle-right{
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome, i am still working on the final version i will update it as soon as posible!

Comment: what do you want to do is it for a presentation or you plan to click on the arrows ? an move the pictures? if so you just need one `a.ui-carousel-handle-left` and one `a.ui-carousel-handle-right`

Comment: those will be buttons triggering transition to next/previous image. Images will be inside `<li>`. I'm also playing around with it still. If I set a top in px, eg `100px`, the buttons stay where they are, so since `css:top: percentage` is based on the containing block, I believe the `ui-content` defined by jQuery Mobile changes and throws the handle "off". Let's see.

Comment: ok la c'est a toi de voir, fais moi signe si tu as encore besoin de mon aide. Bonne chance!

Comment: je parle Francais une petite peu... merci beaucoup. je vais continue mon cherche pour on solution. Will post if I find something.

Comment: Please keep comments in English.

Comment: @BoltClock ok sorry my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Seems `position:relative:top` is not the right thing to use here. After much meedling this works ([JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ofuhaw/1281/edit))...

I moved both link elements to after the list containing my images. Then I switched to `float:left/right` and negative `margin-top` like so:

```
 .ui-carousel-handle-left:not(.ui-carousel-handle-inset) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    margin: -60% 0 0 -1.25em;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
 }
 .ui-carousel-handle-right:not(.ui-carousel-handle-inset) {
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    margin: -60% -1.25em 0 0;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em;
 }
```

From what I understand on MDN, [**css margin percentage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/margin) are calculated based on the containing element width, while [**css top percentage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) is based on the containing elements height.

It seems my problem originated from my containing elements height being recalculated by jQuery Mobile (which I'm doing this for) while its width seems to not be changed. Hence `margin-top` works, while `pos:relative:top` does not.